# How to pass multi-valued attribute for any classification approach

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, data-science

I have a feature "skills" which is a multi-valued parameter. I want to use it as a feature for classification. I don't know how to use it to train my model.

For example, a job has certain required skills (say Java, Node.js, MVC), which can be different for different jobs. I have to use skills as one of the parameter.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

A common way to deal with multi-valued features is to split them up.
If you know all possible skills in your dataset, create a feature for each individual skill. If the skill is present in a sample the corresponding feature is 1 otherwise it is 0.

For example

```
skill = "Java,MVC"
```

turns into multiple features:

```
Java = 1, Node.js = 0, MVC = 1
```

The downside of this method is that your feature space explodes if you have many different skills. This means that your model becomes prone to overfitting.

Comment: You could do the opposite (encode all possible combinations) which is very efficient on runtime but requires quite an effort to encode all combinations in the beginning. If you have less <100 combinations I would suggest this approach .

Comment: @rpd  I doubt that she/he has less than 7 different skills and that could be a problem since the combinations grow exponentially 2^(number of skills). Besides, it is less useful for the machine-learning application since two different candidates with only one differing skill are treated as completely different combinations. (the similarity is lost)

Comment: In that case you can use TF - IDF as  a "preprocessing" step on skills and use thresholds in order to quantify the differences.